# MySQL Manager: You tried to execute empty string,please type sql command into sql edit field and execute

Tags: mysql, mysql-manager

I am facing a very strange issue of executing query into mysql manager tool

i exported my database from phpmyadmin using wamp server and now on client's server i am trying to run that query and it gives me that error.

any one help me how to resolve this issue?there is no blank space in this query.

any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a semicolon situated such that it gives rise to an empty statement?  For example, at the very beginning, or immediately (whitespace aside) following another semicolon?

Comment: at the end of every statement that script contains semi colon and i have noticed one more thing i can execute single statement only and mysql manager highlighting one single area either its insert statement or create table statement. do i need to remove semi colon from all the statements to make this work in a single iteration?

Comment: i got my answer thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i found solution to my problem, let me explain here: that might help someone else with same issue.

there were two issues:

1) The major issue was semi colon after each statement(that wamp generated).
2) When you copy script into mysql manager query browser it does not change its color and query area remains grey that means empty area.

so when you run execute it due to grey area it says there is no query inside the query browser.

so in that case you need to click in the query browser, and if you have semi colons with each statement it will allow you to execute single statement only.

if you wish you execute all the script in a single iteration just remove the semi colon after the each statement and whole query browser area will become white and hit execute button to make this work. (see attachment for more details)

Thank you![image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

setp 1: open MySql adminstrative
setp 2: goto menu Tool > MySql Query Browser
setp 3: goto menu File > New Script Tab
setp 4: type or copy paste your query and execute query .